# О согласовании

Tags: согласование

Имеется такой отрывок текста: "Одной рукой он прижимал к боку охапку тонких палок, а второй волок за собой то ли огромную сухую ветку, то ли небольшое дерево. Оно оставляло за собой борозды в земле, точно плуг пахаря". Так вот, меня тут смущает "оно". Ведь не ясно, что это: ветка или дерево, то есть, "она" или "оно".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Интересный вопрос. Думаю, авторам стоит избегать таких конструкций, где возникают такие неясности. В данном примере автор, видимо, заявляет, что герой несет всё-таки небольшое дерево, а не ветку.

Comment: А может быть, ОНО - это нечто, похожее на огромную сухую ветку или на небольшое дерево? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

> > > А может быть, ОНО - это нечто, похожее на огромную сухую ветку или на небольшое дерево? ;-)

Именно так, даже без смайлика.
Никого не смутит если за конструкцией типа "... второй волок за собой то ли огромную сухую ветку, то ли **ствол небольшого дерева**", последует "Это оставляло за собой...".
"Оно" здесь именно "нечто", местоимение "неопределенного" рода. По типу "А как оно работает?", "А почему оно здесь", употреблемых в разговоре в отношении непонятных или неуцстановленных объектов.